# How can I hide feedback in CSV output of a hive query?

Tags: sql, hive, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

I have a query.sql file which looks like this:

```sql
set feedback off
spool "path/to/output.csv"
select fieldname from tablename;
spool off;
```

And in SQL Developer (v. 18.3.0 on CentOS) I run scripts.sql which looks like this:

```sql
@query.sql
```

But I get the following message in the script output

```
set
--------------------------------------------------
feedback off is undefined
```

The saved CSV is perfect in every way except at the bottom it prints a blank row followed by "X rows selected." which is what I'd like to be rid of.

Comment: version of SQL Developer? the recent versions do support SET FEEDBACK OFF

Comment: @thatjeffsmith 18.3.0. From what I'm seeing on google, 18.3 addressed some bugs in SET FEEDBACK behavior, implying that my version should have support for it.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me, note i'm doing this on an Oracle connection, but it should work on hive as well since the SET commands are client based

[image]

This is running on version 19.4

```
clear screen
set sqlformat csv
set feedback off
spool /Users/thatjeffsmith/output.csv
select first_name, last_name from employees fetch first 3 rows only;
spool off
!cat /Users/thatjeffsmith/output.csv
```